# Accepting values of array in a function and using it in another function, How is this Works in C?

Tags: arrays, c, function

in a program to accept an array and display it on the console using functions getArray() and displayArray() how this program works as it Accepts values of array in  function getArray() and uses it in the function displayArray() without returning any values from the first function?

I tried this program and failed to get result, then found this one in youTube comment section and I tried it and got results! I want to know how this program works ?

*Q:Write a program to accept an array and display it on the console using function?
a.Program should contain 3 functions including main() function,
main() - {
Declare an array.
Call function getArray().
Call function displayArray() }.
getArray() -
Get values to the array.
displayArray() -
Display the array values*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getArray(int);
void displayArray(int);
int main(void) {
    int limit;
    printf("Enter The Size of the Array :");
    scanf("%d",&limit);
    getArray(limit);
    displayArray(limit);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void getArray(int limit){
    int i,a[100];
    printf("Enter The Values of Array :\n");
    for(i=0;i<limit;i++){
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
}

void displayArray(int limit){
    int i,b[100];
    printf("Your Array is :\n");
    for(i=0;i<limit;i++){
        printf(" %d\t",b[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Your program doesn't work at all. Your functions have two separate and unrelated arrays. You should define one single array in the `main` function, and pass it to the "get" and "display" functions as arguments.

Comment: This program only “works” because it’s relying on undefined behaviour.  When you return from getArray, by coincidence displayArray puts b[] in the same location a[] was, and the memory hadn’t been cleared yet.  This answer would fail any grading as it’s relying on behaviour outside the language, and it would break if you did anything else inbetween.

Answer (score 2):

Array `a` in `getArray` is a local variable that gets destroyed when it goes out of scope. Array `b` in `displayArray` is also a local variable (local to `displayArray`) and has no relationship with `a` in `getArray`. You need to pass the same array to both functions.

One way could be to allocate the needed memory for the array in `main` and pass that, along with the number of elements in the array, to the two functions.

Example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// a is now a pointer to the first element in the array:
void getArray(int *a, int limit) { 
    printf("Enter The Values of Array :\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
}

// b is now a pointer to the first element in the array:
void displayArray(int *b, int limit) {
    printf("Your Array is :\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
        printf(" %d\t", b[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void) {
    int limit;
    printf("Enter The Size of the Array :");

    if(scanf("%d", &limit) != 1 || limit < 1) return EXIT_FAILURE;

    // allocate memory for `limit` number of `int`s:
    int *arr = malloc(limit * sizeof *arr);
    if(arr == NULL) return EXIT_FAILURE;

    getArray(arr, limit);     // pass arr + limit
    displayArray(arr, limit); // pass arr + limit

    free(arr);                // and free the memory when done
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

void getArray(int);
void displayArray(int);

int array[100];

void main()
{
    int limit;
    printf("enter the array size you want\n");
    scanf("%d",&limit);
    getArray(limit);
    displayArray(limit);
}

void getArray(int limit)
{
    printf("enter the array element you want\n");
    for(int i=0;i<limit;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    }
}

void displayArray(int limit)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",array[i]);
        printf("\t");
    }
}
```